# Ignore resources using kustomize

Tags: argocd, kustomize

I'm deploying argocd onto your cluster but want to ignore dex server resources (sa, deployment, roles)

Is there a way to ignore the resources based on their label `argocd-dex-server` (all resources have this label)

Is it `$patch delete` or any other better approach ?

Comment: I typically use `$patch: delete` at the root of the CR

Comment: @LostJon Yep ended up using it :)